# How do you split a really large .dat file into XML files?

Tags: r

This is my first time dealing with really large files, and with .dat and XML files! Upon trying to read the data in R I get an instant error as it is far too big.

I have been told they are a concatenation of XML files and i 'just need to split it'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answwer to your first question: how to read and split to xml..

```
library( data.table )

#read in as single lines
DT <- fread( "./temp/NTISDATD-ANPR-2020-05-10-Day8.dat", sep = "" )
#read each row as xml, store in list
L <- apply( DT, 1, xml2::read_xml )
# process further
...
```